# CSS animation infinite not working

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following code:

```
.dangerous_b {
    width: 636px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url('/media/anim.png');
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    animation: bganim 100ms steps(1, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes bganim {
    from { background-position: 0px 0px; }
    to { background-position: 0px -72px; }
}
```

But the animation is only playing once. What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT: Note that the animation plays out *once*, so there is a visual difference. But I want the animation to *loop*.**

Btw: Here is the picture I used: <kbd>https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJcCl.png</kbd>

---

**2nd EDIT: Here is the code snippet**

```css
.dangerous_b {
    width: 636px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJcCl.png');
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    animation: bganim 100ms steps(1, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes bganim {
    from { background-position: 0px 0px; }
    to { background-position: 0px -72px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="dangerous_b"></div>
```

---

**3rd EDIT: It's working now with the following code:**

```
.dangerous_b {
    width: 636px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJcCl.png');
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    animation: bganim 100ms steps(1, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes bganim {
    50% { background-position: 0px -72px; }
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/ ^^.

Comment: @Brennced: Noted your edit. In that case can you create a demo with your actual image? Because as you can see in the snippet within the answer, even the first time there is no visual movement.

Comment: @Brennced: Sorry, hadn't seen your 3rd edit before I added a very similar snippet to my answer. If you wish to post your edit as an answer, I will remove mine. Answers section is the correct place to post solutions :)

Answer (score 5):

**Reason:**

Problem is because of the `animation-timing-function`. A value of `steps(1,start)` means that the animation has only one step and it happens right at the start of the animation itself.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function) (picked from definition for `step-start` but it is same as `steps(1, start)`):

> Using this timing function, the animation ***jumps immediately to the end state and stay in that position until the end of the animation***.

First step of the first iteration happens as soon as the page is loaded (or class is added) and due to it, the background image immediately moves to the position indicated inside the `to` frame. For the 2nd iteration, the move back to its original position (`from` frame) and then to the final position (`to` frame) again happens instantaneously meaning that you don't get to see any visual difference and it looks as though the element is staying at its place without any animation.

```css
.dangerous_b {
  width: 636px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fA80qQc.png');
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  animation: bganim 1s steps(1, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes bganim {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0px -72px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='dangerous_b'></div>
```

The same behavior can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34ona3do/2/) also. This is not my creation but is an adaptation of the demo present as [designmodo](http://designmodo.com/steps-css-animations/). The first car never actually moves (or is never actually seen to move) because the step happens right at the start.

---

**Solution 1: Use two steps and double the ending background position**

When the no. of steps is set to two, the animation happens as a two step process where the first step again happens at the start of the animation (because of `start` parameter). This means:

- During the first step, the background moves to half distance between the start and the end state.
- Since 1st step happens right at the start, `background-position` is never `0px 0px`. (Do note that, I have doubled the end `background-position`).
- In the 2nd step, the background moves to the final position. Because the background images are repeated, `0px -144px` is equal to `0px 0px`. This creates an illusion of the background moving to its original position.

```css
.dangerous_b {
  width: 636px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fA80qQc.png');
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  animation: bganim 1s steps(2, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes bganim {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0px -144px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='dangerous_b'></div>
```

---

**Solution 2: Use just one step but change the end position to half way**

For some reason, this seems to mimic a two step animation.

- In the first half, the background moves to the position indicated within `50%` frame.
- During second half, it seems to go back to the original position (or `100%` position, both of which are the same). Thus when next iteration starts and the image jumps, it moves from `0%` or `100%` position to `50%` position and ends up producing the required animation effect.

```css
.dangerous_b {
  width: 636px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fA80qQc.png');
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  animation: bganim 1s steps(1, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes bganim {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 0px -72px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='dangerous_b'></div>
```

Comment: @Brennced: I have added another version to the answer. If you add an intermediate frame, it seems to work. I suspect this is again because the background keeps going back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, it now takes 1 frame to run your animation. 
Since your background image is moving out of sight, you won't see it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function#The_steps()_class_of_timing-functions